# Subcaption - vertical alignment of vertically arranged subfigures relative to the right edge

Tags: vertical-alignment, subcaption

I want to align two vertically arranged tikz plots relative to their right boundary. They both contain a coordinate system - e.g., a Bode diagram. Due to different y labels and ticks, they have different widths.
Thus centering them, the x-axis are not vertically aligned.
I can adjust it manually by adjusting the height of the figures and using a \hfill in combination with a minipage:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.95\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=6cm]{plot1}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5cm}
            \hfill
  \end{minipage}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:plot1}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.95\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=6cm]{plot2}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:plot2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:plots}
\end{figure}
```

This is not very robust, as it relies on the figures having the same raw height. If not, there's a lot of try and error involved... 
Is there a way to do this more elegant and robust using the subcaption package, e.g., similar to anchor=east functionality available in tikz?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? It's a solution that uses a `minipage` inside the `figure` environment, and everything inside the `minipage` (basically, two `subfigure` environments) is typeset ragged-left (aka flushright).

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
  \raggedleft % <-- new
  \begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plot1}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:plot1}
  \end{subfigure}

  \bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plot2}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:plot2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:plots}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, that seems to go into the right direction. Thanks! 
However, if I use \includegraphics[height=6cm], the alignment gets lost.

Comment: @sts - I'm not sure I follow your comment. Did you *add* the option `\includegraphics[height=6cm]` to the exisiting option, or did you *replace* `width=\textwidth` with `\includegraphics[height=6cm]`? In the former case, the right-alignment should be preserved. Please be specific as to what you're doing.

Comment: I replaced \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plot*} with \includegraphics[height=6cm]{plot*}.